# C++ compare vector iterator with instance

Tags: c++, vector

I need to write a function that removes the received element from a vector.
I think the way to do this is to parse the vector and compare the iterator with the reference passed. The problem is that I cannot compare the type iterator with type object reference...

**BELOW THE ACTUAL CODE (Edit: originally I posted a much simplified version)**

```
struct BufferPoint{int x; int y; float pressure; };

class QueueState
{
public:
        VectorCurve *curveVector;
        RasterCurve *curveRaster;
        vector<BufferPoint> *curveBuffer;
        QueueState(vector<BufferPoint> *_b, VectorCurve *_v, RasterCurve *_r){ curveBuffer= _b; curveVector = _v; curveRaster = _r;};
};


vector<vector<BufferPoint>> queueBuffers;
vector<QueueState> queueStates;


[...]


// FIND AND REMOVE A BUFFER OBJECT
for(std::vector<QueueState>::iterator it = queueStates.begin(); it != queueStates.end(); ++it) 
{   

    //Remove buffer from pool (queue)
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if((it->curveVector->state == CURVEDATA_STATE_FINISHED) & (it->curveRaster->state == CURVEDATA_STATE_FINISHED))
    {
        queueBuffers.erase(std::find(queueBuffers.begin(), queueBuffers.end(), *(it->curveBuffer)));  // <-- THIS DOESNT WORK. CHECK BELOW FOR ERROR MESSAGE (1)
        queueStates.erase(it);
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

(1) This is the message I get from the compiler:

```
Error   error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const BufferPoint' (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 2956
```

Comment: myRef is a pointer to a vector. Not a reference to an element of buffer.

Comment: "reference to one element of 'buffer'" means: `int& myRef = buffer[ some_correct_index ];`

Comment: Where do you get myRef from? What do you really want to do? Remove all items with a specific value? How do you decide what to remove?

Comment: `myRef` should be declared `int&` (for a true reference) of `int*` for a pointer which 'refers' to a vector element.

Comment: ... or ideally it is an actual iterator into your vector, which makes the removal downright trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a *real* iterator referencing an element in your vector, the removal is trivial::

```
std::vector<int>::iterator myIter = ... get iterator to your element ...
buffer.erase(myIter);
```

If instead you have a *value* prospect and you want the **first** element of that value removed:

```
int myVal = ... whatever the value is ...
buffer.erase(std::find(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), myVal));
```

Finally, if you want to remove **all** elements matching the *value* prospect:

```
int myVal = ... whatever the value is ...
buffer.erase(std::remove(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), myVal), buffer.end());
```

I hazard to suggest one of these will likely fit the bill far better than what you're currently doing. Judging by the input on other answers, I suggest you try the *last* one. If you're the least-bit curious how it works, think of it as doing the following:

Given this sequence:

```
1 3 4 2 3 5 6 3 7
```

Now suppose you want to remove all the `3`'s. The `std::remove` will transform your vector to the following via element *swaps*

```
1 4 2 5 6 7 3 3 3
return it --^
```

The `buffer.erase()` method then erases from the returned iterator to the end of the sequence leaving you with simply:

```
1 4 2 5 6 7
```

This is commonly called the [remove/erase idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom)

---

**EDIT**: OP requests how to do this with his custom structure.

In you case, just define the following after the `BufferPoint` definition:

```
struct BufferPoint {int x; int y; float pressure; };

inline bool operator ==(const BufferPoint& lhs, const BufferPoint& rhs)
{
    return lys.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y;
}
```

I wasn't sure if you wanted `pressure` in that equality comparison. If so, add it in as a condition, but note floating point roundoff is a pesky thing to deal with. if you can avoid it, do so. This is probably the simplest way to get what you're after.

Comment: That's actually very elegant! The problem I have now is that my actual type is not int but a custom class and hence I run into this error: `Error error C2678: binary == : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type const BufferPoint (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 2956code`

Comment: You can still do it using a *comparator*. as the third argument to `std::remove` rather than a value. It is significantly more involved, but still doable. Can you post the type declaration for `BufferPoint` (in your question, please, not in comments)?

Comment: what do you mean using a comparator as the third argument to std::remove ?

Comment: Post the definition of `BufferPoint` in your question and I'll show you. Or you can simply defined an equality operator for `BufferPoint`, i.e.  `bool operator ==(const BufferPoint& left, const BufferPoint& right)` function and the rest will take care of itself.

Comment: I edited my question to contain the actual code, could you please have a look at the actual data structure and letting me know how you would apply your solution? THANK YOU.

Comment: @mαττjαĸøb Done. that should likely be all you need. I'm assuming you care about the x/y in determining equality; not the `float` member, which frankly gets dicey to include in equality comparisons. I was also unsure where the `t` variable in your code was coming from, but not sure I need to know at this point.

Answer (score 1):

First [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) has no function member called `.remove`, it has [`.erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase). Second, after each erase all iterators will be get invalid. So you should the updated iterator returns from `.erase` method.

> Iterators and references to the erased elements and to the elements between them and the end of the container are invalidated. The past-the-end iterator is also invalidated.

```
for (vector<int>::iterator b=buff.begin(); it!=buffer.end(); )
{

   if(*b == myRef) 
       b = buffer.erase(b);
   else 
      ++b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use erase method,try this

```
vector<int> buffer;

int myRef ; //reference to one element of 'buffer'

for(std::vector<int>::iterator b = buffer.begin(); b != buffer.end(); ++b)
{
  if(*b == myRef)       // <-- THIS CLEARLY DOESNT WORK
  {
    b = buffer.erase(b);// <-- REMOVE THE FOUND ELEMENT FROM THE VECTOR
    b--;
  }
}
```